# Wordpress How to fix URL using .htaccess?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am using wordpress, i have some URL issue.

My current URL is :  http://www.example.com/states/?q=ohio

I want URL :www.example.com/states/ohio

i want to remove ? mark form url.

without adding code in htaccess when i call URL http://www.example.com/states/ohio. it given me page not found error.

so how could i solve this issue?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Introduction_to_Blogging#Pretty_Permalinks

Comment: wordpress handle that automatically you just need to make sure you set permalinks using the settings API on your dashboard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: Settings > Permalink > tick postname option

Answer (score 0):

Could use something like this as your htacces file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^states/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ /states/?q=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Visiting  http://www.example.com/states/ohio/ should now resolve to /states/?q=ohio

If not check your apache logs and that the page can be directly accessed

Comment: still not working query string still appearing in URL.

Comment: add that to you htaccess file. then try the URL with a forward slash on the end

Comment: @samir Did you enabled mod_rewrite module in you apache server ? What server you are using ?

Comment: is the htaccess file saved in the root of your site?

Comment: so what is the error? What does the apache log show?

Comment: i said still ? mark is appearing in URL. i want URL like this www.example.com/states/ohio/

Comment: so if you visit  http://www.example.com/states/ohio//  it directs back to the ? address? if so you need to remove the other redirect & clear cache to try again

Comment: then there is probably another redirect in place. somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing previously using add_rewrite_rule.

Try to use this code,

```
 function custom_rewrite_rule() {
      add_rewrite_rule(        
            'states/([^/]*)/?',        
            'index.php/states/?q=$1',        
            'top' );
    }

    add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Do not forget to update your permalink after adding this into `"function.php"` file.

It should work for you. Thanks.

Comment: i used above code in my theme functions.php and also update permalink but still query string is appearing in my URL.

Comment: @samir , check your .htacces file after updating your permalink structure. It should be updated with this: "RewriteRule ^states/([^/]*)/? /index.php/states/?q=$1 [QSA,L]". Try to load this link: http://www.example.com/states/ohio directely.

Comment: It's given me page not found Error. :(

Comment: my pleasure :-)

Comment: this code is not working on cpanel , it's given me page not found error.